# create datamember with two types

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a telegram message class and consume their web services. telegram message has a property name chat, which can be type of a user or group chat. like this:

```
chat    User or GroupChat   Conversation the message belongs to — user in case of a private message, GroupChat in case of a group
```

how can i create a data-member with two types? i have now idea how should i ask my question. its little new for me, so please accept my apologize if its so obvious.
thanks.

**Update**

Thank you so much. i changed my message class like this:

```
namespace bot.TelegramUpdate
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Message
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int message_id;
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public User from;
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public int date;
        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public IChat chat;
    }
}
```

and also here is my `Ichat` interface:

```
interface IChat
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

class User : IChat
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string first_name;
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string last_name;
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string username;
}

class GroupChat : IChat
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string title;
}
```

but the problem is when i change the class, telegram fails to call my web service. i have no idea why!

Comment: create message class with two  properties one for private and one for group converstation.if you explain more ,people can help you better.maybe this is not the only way to solve it

Comment: bool type? would you please explain little more?

Comment: Are User and GroupChat derived from a base class?

Comment: both just have one member in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create two members of different types and check which one is not null?

You also should read about [interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx).

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    interface IChat
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class User : IChat
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string first_name;
        public string last_name;
        public string username;
    }

    class GroupChat : IChat
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title;
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public IChat Chat { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyClass foo = new MyClass();
        foo.Chat = new User();

        MyClass bar = new MyClass();
        bar.Chat = new GroupChat();

        if(foo.Chat.GetType() == typeof(User))
            Console.WriteLine("foo has User");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("foo has GroupChat");

        if(bar.Chat.GetType() == typeof(User))
            Console.WriteLine("bar has User");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("bar has GroupChat");
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant do it. if i just one add extra  member to message class, telegram failed to send the a new update to me.(Im using web hook.)

Comment: thank you so much dear @micnyk. would you please tell me how can I use your idea as web service input? i mean telegram calls my web service with message and expects a user or group as chat. its the part i dont get it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to make a setting? That's typically done like this:

```
public enum ChatType { User = 1, GroupChat = 2 }

public class Message
{
  public ChatType Chat;
}
```

You could also make an interface or base class that could end up being different types of chat objects.

```
public interface Chat
{
  // chat properties
}

public User : Chat
{
}

public GroupChat: Chat
{
}

public Processor
{
  public void Receive(Message mesage)
  {
     var user = message.Chat as User;
     if(user != null)
     // Handle user specific
  }

  public Message Send()
  {
     if(single)
       return new Message() { Chat = new User() };
     else
       return new Message() { Chat = new ChatGroup() };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but its not gonna work. where should i put the Processor method?

Comment: Processor as in MessageProcessor. It's just a stub to put some code in. Look at how the properties are assigned and use that in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Have both User and GroupChat implement an interface. Something like `IConversationOwner`.  Then your member type can just be `IConversationOwner`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Object as Type and check with if(obj is User).. / if(obj is GroupChat)